# Synchronization usage

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

- I have written a program to print `n  o  t  i  f  y`, with all letters separated by a tab.
- I have used inter-thread communication, in which one thread prints one letter followed by another thread printing another, using `wait()` and `notify()`.
- I am getting `n  o  t` as the output. What about `i  f  y`? Why isn't it getting printed?

Code:

```
package multi_threading; 

 public class test_value implements Runnable{
    static String name="notify";
    Thread t;
    static int len;
    boolean val=false;
    static int i;
    public test_value(){}
    public test_value(test_value obj,String msg){
        t=new Thread(obj,msg);
        t.start();
    }
    public static void main(String args[]){
        len=name.length();
        test_value obj=new test_value();
        new test_value(obj,"Child1"); 
        new test_value(obj,"Child2");
    }
    public void run(){
        synchronized(this){
          while(i<len){
          System.out.println("I got "+name.charAt(i));
          i++;
          val=!val;
          while(val){
              try{
                   wait();
                }catch(InterruptedException e){
                    System.out.println("Interrupted");
               }
           }
          notify();
        }
      }   
    }
 }
```

Comment: Please use the java naming convention. Also I think you might just need to call the `Thread.join()` method on the two objects. Finally, there is so much wrong with the class above: you should use an ExecutorService instead of creating a thread; you are using a new instance of your class to run an instance of your class for no reason; you shouldn't use wait/notify as they are too low level: use one of the utility classes in java.util.concurrent.

Comment: @GiovanniBotta wait and notify are fine if you know how to use them

Comment: This is one of the most strange multi threading attempt I've seen. I can hardly make heads or tails of this code

Comment: @Cruncher this clearly does not seem to be the case! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not only do you only get 'n', 'o', and 't', but your program does not end, either.... :)

You need to change the `while(val)` to be `if (val)`

All the best, (and debugging is your friend). Also, class names should be 'Capitalized camel case'. Your class should be called `TestValue` and not `test_value`.

Comment: So he wants while(val). val is supposed to get changed in another thread.

Comment: But, there is no guarantee that the other thread gets the synchronization back on the notify.... I have run the coe myself, and the thread that does the notify() immediately claims the synchronization back again in the loop

Comment: rolfl is true about if usage.I used it and it is working.If a thread is waiting and other thread notifies it,there is no assurance that waiting thread gets notified because of while loop.Use if and it works!

Answer (score 0):

Better yet, you don't need val at all.

```
synchronized(this){
    while(i<len){
        System.out.println("I got "+name.charAt(i) + ", " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        i++;    
        try{
            notify();
            wait();
        }catch(InterruptedException e){
            System.out.println("Interrupted");
        }
    }
}
```

Ran this and got output:

```
I got n, Child2
I got o, Child1
I got t, Child2
I got i, Child1
I got f, Child2
I got y, Child1
```

By using the accepted answers code I got output:

```
I got n, Child1
I got o, Child2
I got t, Child2
I got i, Child1
I got f, Child1
I got y, Child2
```

This one is not truly alternating threads like you want it to. 
This stems from the fact that notify does not actually give the lock up. It just means that when you do give up the lock(when you wait) you'll let one of the waiting threads know that it's their turn to run.

Answer (score -1):

your variable

```
boolean val=false;
```

is not static, so each thread has its own value, make it static

```
static boolean val=false;
```

Comment: Downvoted because, even though you are right about the static, you are wrong about the threads having different values.... Both threads run the same `runnable` instance (hence only one `val` )